# Storing more than required elements in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to get a number of values stored in a list and then that list should act as a value to a key in a dictionary.
The problem is to get the names of `'n'` students and store marks of 3 subjects in a list and make a dictionary with it i.e.

`Marksheet = {'Name': [mark1,mark2,mark3]}`

But while giving inputs to the list I'm forced to take in `n x subjects` inputs in my list instead of just 3.
I've attached my code for reference -

```
marksheet = {}
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
marks = []
for i in range(n):
    key = input("Enter names:")
    num = 3
    for a in range(num):
    ele = float(input("Enter marks: "))
    marks.append(ele)
    marksheet[key] = marks
print(marks)

print(marksheet)
avg = sum(marks)/3
print(f'avg')
```

Comment: You should put `marks = []` inside the loop or you will keep appending to the same list for all students. But the actual question is how to ask for multiple marks on one line, right?

Comment: It is not very clear what the intended input format is. Can you show an example?

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, your suggestion works

Comment: Any suggestions on how to find the average of the marks

Comment: Note that the line `sum(marks)` now will not, you will have to group all items from `marksheet` and sum them.

Comment: I want to find the average of each individual student, any suggestions for that?

Comment: @LearningMathematics Sure, I take in the number of students as n, I enter the name of the first student and then using a loop I enter the marks of 3 of his/her subjects and then the next student's

Comment: You can update the data structure used as output to support the average mark of each student: `marksheet[key]["marks"] = marks` followed by `marksheet[key]["avg"] = sum(marks)/len(marks)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask for all the marks on the same line, you can `split` the input, `map` the substrings to `float`, and collect those in a `list`. Note that this way, the number of marks is not limited to `3` (or guaranteed to be the same for all students) but just how many space-separated numbers the user enters.

```
marksheet = {}
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
for i in range(n):
    key = input("Enter names: ")
    marks = list(map(float, input("Enter marks: ").split()))
    marksheet[key] = marks
```

If you want to keep using that inner loop, make sure to re-initialize `marks` in each iteration so you do not reuse the same list for each name:

```
...
for i in range(n):
    marks = []
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help to place the list inside your loop to clear it for each name.

For example:

```
marksheet = {}
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
for i in range(n):
    marks = []
    key = input("Enter names:")
    num = 3
    for a in range(num):
        ele = float(input("Enter marks: "))
        marks.append(ele)
        marksheet[key] = marks
    print(marks)

print(marksheet)
avg = sum(marks)/3
print('avg {}'.format(avg))
```

I also changed the print statement at the end to:

```
print('avg {}'.format(avg))
```